# How do I install Groovy?

Tags: software-installation, java

When I try to run this:

```
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

I get this big error:

```
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4) ...
Downloading...
--2012-04-28 18:43:39--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 96.17.181.40, 96.17.181.49
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|96.17.181.40|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-04-28 18:43:39--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 184.50.22.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|184.50.22.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-04-28 18:43:40--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|96.17.181.40|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100% 47.2K=0.1s

2012-04-28 18:43:40 (47.2 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of groovy:
 groovy depends on default-jre-headless | sun-java6-jre; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java7-installer which provides default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package sun-java6-jre is not installed.
dpkg: error processing groovy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 groovy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already have Java installed in my PC. When I run :

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recovered from this error by doing :

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

This will prompt you to remove the `openjdk` that have been installed in your system. Proceed with it. After the `openjdk` have been removed from your pc, you can do :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:groovy-dev/groovy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

This installs the stable version. After that do this, in your terminal :

```
groovy -version
```

This should give you the output :

```
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_24 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Comment: Since the above PPA repository is quite outdated/unmaintained, I'd also recommend using the GVM way to install Groovy as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Instead, I simply installed the [GVM (Groovy enVironment Manager)](http://gvmtool.net/) and used that to install groovy.

Comment: This site seems too slow, at least I can't open it, may be the best way is use   SDKMAN http://groovy-lang.org/install.html